# What should be my local database host name in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am installing wordpress on my localhost using XAMPP, so as you can see in this picture http://image.prntscr.com/image/cadb8b8d496c4f75a3d41ba34ef2487a.png 
I wrote this in my database host "localhost:8080/" and when i click on submit. Google chrome says "waiting for localhost" at the left bottom side (see the pic). Can someone help me?

Comment: Database is this: `localhost:3306` On port `8080` is the apache server listening. You can leave the 3306, since it is the default port for mysql. so you can write `localhost` there. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

`using the default port number (3306):`

Comment: Only for you i guess

Comment: Please... Apache is usually running on port 80 or 8080. 3306 is the default port for mysql. not only for me. this is the default setting in my.cnf.

Comment: This is the message which i get when i try "localhost" or "localhost:3306" http://i.imgur.com/zEP3HhA.png

Comment: try `127.0.0.1` maybe you've not set your `hosts` file. or `127.0.0.1:3306`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 Shows me the same error and when i type "127.0.0.1:8080" if says, waiting for "127.0.0.1.

Comment: Forget `8080`. Are you sure, your username / password / dbname is ok? And do not write `/` or anything, only `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Hey mate, at first my apache was not running. So i opened xampp control panal > apache config > apache(httpd:conf) > changed some ports from 80 to 8080

Comment: I think i can write anything in database name, password,username right? Yeah, i tried to remove 8080

Comment: That is the apache. Forget apache. Open a shell, and type this: `mysql -u kchere -p KCDB`. It will ask you the password. Type it, are you see this: `mysql>` ? You can logout from here by `quit;`

Comment: Nope. you should give the proper user/ pass and database name to there. WP need to know the credentials how to connect to the server.

Comment: What should be the DP name, password, username? See my SS in the question, they are not right?

Comment: Sorry but what is shell?

Comment: Oh got it, in XAMPP

Comment: When it ask me for password, and i type it. It say  access denied for user 
"kchere "@" localhost" <using password: YES>

Comment: When you installed the XAMP, it asked you a root password for mysql. Then you need to go to phpmyadmin. and create a new database, and a new user/pass. See the XAMPP documentation. I can not help more.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your advise and help, really appreciated :)